# Do all irc commands start with /?

Tags: irc

Or there are some that do not? What are they?

Comment: @Matt unless asker is about to ask for a regex to identify IRC commands :)

Answer (score 7):

No! The IRC protocol uses no /s. For example, changing your nick is done with a "NICK name" command, and regular speech is done with a "PRIVMSG #channel :text" command. It's up to the client to provide methods to use these commands, and for that, the control character could be anything!
However, this does mean that most clients stick to something consistent, so it is likely all commands will be preceeded by a / in your client.

Comment: Nice answer. Although I wish someone made a IRC client with command / insert modes like VI.

Comment: that would be pretty great - can't irssi be configured like that, though? ish.

Comment: Haven't looked into it, I've been using Colloquy lately.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I'm using Miranda-IM - and no other networks! It's only a little blight on my geek-cred :P

Comment: It'd be worse if you used AIM. :) Make up for it by using VI for writing a research paper.

Comment: +1. I can also add, to check the IRC RFC to see all commonly supported commands: http://irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html

Comment: @Ivan Petrushev: Unfortunately, some commands (like /me (or /action, depending on client)) are totally not in the spec! Generally though, the RFC is a good place to start :P

Comment: So it should be THE RFC plus your irc client documentation :)

Comment: VimIRC - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=931

Answer (score 3):

No.
That's just a way IRC client found to differ from 'normal' text.

You can access to all supported server command by using /quote cmd or /raw cmd

Ex:

```
/quote whois bgy
```

That will send a raw command to the server.

Answer (score -3):

They all start with "/" beacuse you need to differ if you are typing text or commands...

edit:

I need to make this clear. The other answers are right. It isn´t the irc itself that uses /.
It is your client.